# Qt: Low speed when transferring data from remote database

Tags: sql-server, database, qt, optimization, remote-server

I am using Qt5 on Windows7.
I am writing a Qt app to replace an old C# app (written 7-8 years ago). The goal is to connect and transfer data from some remote databases. The remote DB servers are MS SQL Server 2000.
I already have the app running, but I noticed the data transfer takes much more time comparing to the old C# app...
So, I was just wondering what may cause such a low data transfer rate?
Maybe I forgot something or maybe I am doing something wrong...
Here is the code I am using to connect to the remote database(s):

```
void RemoteDB::openConnection(const QString & serverIP, const QString & dbName)
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

    db.setDatabaseName(QString("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;").arg(serverIP).arg(dbName));
    db.open("user", "password");
}
```

Query code:

```
SqlRecord record;
QSqlQuery query(QSqlDatabase::database());
if(query.exec("SELECT * FROM VehicleStatus") == true)
{
    while(query.next() == true)
    {
        record.Vehicle    = query.value("Vehicle").toInt();
        record.Status     = query.value("Status").toInt();
        record.AppVersion = query.value("AppVersion").toString();
        record.DateTime   = query.value("DateTime").toString();
        ...
    }
}
```

Please help, any idea?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: You should also post the code of the queries

Comment: Are there other fields in the records, or just the 4 you're using ?

Comment: @Ilya: The DB record has 17 fields, of which I'm using 13. (I put only 4 in the code snippet above and `...` not to waste space and time)

Comment: OK, so you could test if only selecting the 13 fields you're using makes a difference

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. I tested and I can see some improvement, yet I am still behind the speed of the old C# app. Nevertheless, it is nice/better to fetch less remote data :) Regards! SG.

Comment: OK. Do you know if the C# app uses the  same ODBC driver ?

Comment: I really don't know what to answer. But I guess it's not the same driver...

Comment: See my answer then. If you're not using the right driver, the performance difference on SQL Server can be huge (in my experience).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside trimming the fat (i.e. only selecting the fields you need instead of `*`), check that you're using the best ODBC driver possible.

SQL Server has a "ODBC SQL Server Native Client" that you can install and use, it should be faster than the default ODBC driver. It might already be installed on your PC, but not selected for your data source, or you can try to install it from some dusty SQL Server 2000 DVD (or was it CDs back then ? or - not kidding - *floppy disks* ?), or [from a more recent SQL Server version](http://www.connectionstrings.com/download-sql-server-native-client/). YMMV.

Not sure about C#, but a C# app has probably access to a fast-line driver that doesn't need ODBC.